# If I don't know the content in the file, how should I read the content and store different parts that separated by whitespace?

Tags: c, scanf

Here I have a example about reading file in c. For example, if I have a file on the computer called "file" with some string "a b c". If I want to print them out, I can use the code below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char str1[10], str2[10], str3[10];
   FILE * fp;

   fp = fopen ("file", "r");

   fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s", str1, str2, str3);

   printf("|%s| ", str1 );
   printf("|%s| ", str2 );
   printf("|%s| ", str3 );

   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

And it will print"|a| |b| |c|".

What if I don't know the length of string in the file.
So if I have"a b c d" or "a b" in the file. How should I read the content in the file and print them out?

Comment: Use a loop, and go until you reach the end of the file. You should be able to find the EOF by using functions in the cstd library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html that malloc the right size for you. Exemple at the end of the man